# What is the relationship between a random variable N(0,1) and other continuous random variables?

Tags: statistics, definition

What is the relationship between a random variable with normal distribution (N(0,1)) and other continuous random variables?

Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

Levy and Lindeberg formulated the levy-Lindeberg centra limit theorem:

For {wt} an iid sequence, Ewt=mu, and var(wt)=s2:

Let W=the average of the T wt's. Then: T1/2(W-mu)/s converges in distribution as T goes to infinity to a N(0,1) distribution

Answer (score 3):

This [chart](http://www.johndcook.com/distribution_chart.html) will answer your question.  The arrows indicate relationships between probability distributions. Click on an arrow to see details of the relationship.

Comment: John, Ran across this diagram of yours the other day.  Brilliant and concise and VERY useful !

Comment: Thanks you for your help. The chart helped me to kwon the relationships to all of prob. distributions.